# npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, express, npm

when i trying to install express or any npm packeges getting this type of error(without proxy)(node -v 10.14.2)(npm -v 6.4.1)

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/express/express failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.21.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ankit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-20T15_26_19_314Z-debug.log
```

please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you able to make a GET call to this url http://registry.npmjs.org/express/express? Easiest way to check is to open it in a browser.

Comment: Make sure Your Internet connection is proper , it's getting timeout because of that

Answer (score 3):

if you can't locate .nmprc file. You can try and use

```
npm config delete proxy
```

inside your terminal
then try again:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Hope it work for you too!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today and after doing some research this is what I did.

Inside my `Users/name` it is a file call `.nmprc`. I open it (as a text editor) and there was a proxy that I try to set. something like this:

```
proxy=http://yourorganizationproxy.com:8080
https-proxy=http://yourorganizationproxy.com:8080
```

So  I decided to delete both of then an save the file.

I tried again to execute `npx create-react-app my-app` and it worked.

Hope this works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem before and since I did not need a proxy I deleted the .npmrc file in the User/name directory.
I hope it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Delete the content of .nmprc file resolves the issue.
C:\Users\\.nmprc