# I am new in React and I'm trying to create a React app using the VS Code terminal how to fix it

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, react-native

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://redistry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\youssef\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-20T08_52_11_671Z-debug-0.log

npx create-react-app aosef-app

Comment: Seems similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64448504/npm-err-network-request-to-http-registry-npmjs-org-express-failed-reason-co

Comment: if your Internet connection is not stable enough for it you can try downloading a prebuilt create-react-app boilerplate (don't forget `npm run install` first)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As the error noted: 'This is a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.'

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1-  check if your network is stable or (network problem related to proxy/VPN).
if you are using proxy/VPN try to turn them off and check.

2- Use Vite instead of Create React App

It's preferred to use Vite instead of Create React APP

"Create React APP has been deprecated by the React team"

Vite: https://vitejs.dev/

React docs are recommended Vite now for creating new React Apps if you will use vanilla React without any framework like (Next js, Remix and Gatsby)

Check this: https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project